# Shopify: Get the userErrors from checkoutLineItemsReplace Mutation

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I have this Mutation and I am trying to access to the userErrors but I cannot get the code or field and mesage is the only one I can get or am I doing something wrong? The mutation is working because is removing the products but when some error occurs, I need to get to code or field in order to do a specific action.

```
export const ITEM_REMOVED = gql`
    mutation checkoutLineItemsReplace($lineItems: [CheckoutLineItemInput!] !, $checkoutId: ID!) {
        checkoutLineItemsReplace(lineItems: $lineItems, checkoutId: $checkoutId) {
            userErrors {
                code
                field
                message
            }
            checkout {
                ...CheckoutFragment
            }
        }
    }
    ${CHECKOUT_FRAGMENT}
`


const [mutationItemRemoved] = useMutation(ITEM_REMOVED)

// Item removed
const itemRemoved = (lineItems) => {
    mutationItemRemoved({
        variables: {
            checkoutId: props.checkout.id,
            lineItems,
        },
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r.data.checkoutLineItemsReplace.checkout)
        props.updateCheckout(r.data.checkoutLineItemsReplace.checkout)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.code) // undefined
        console.log(error.field) // undefined
        console.log(error.message)
    })
}
```

Comment: Isn't the errors located in the success response (a.k.a `.then(r => r.errors)`), but under `r.errors` ?

Comment: If that's so then it will never be accessible because  is entering to the .catch block when some error happens

Comment: If it's entering the catch block it means there is a syntax error or something else, not that the query is returning an error. If the query is valid it will always return status 200 and return success even if you pass invalid variant ID. You must have code error not a GraphQL response error. At least that is the default workflow for GraphQL if you are using a specific library for this I can't guarantee nothing.

Comment: I see, I will check it again because the mutations are actually working to add or delete items and the only error I can get is the message in the catch block and is an expected message but the code is the one I need since the message could change at some point. I am using Storefront API and Apollo.

Comment: I don't have Apollo experience a lot so I can't say for sure if they split the response there and throw an error if there are GraphQL errors. This needs to be answered by someone with more experience there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Shopify haven't implemented a `code` return on `userErrors`. They will return a code on `errors` which include extensions. But `userErrors` seem to only return `field` and `message`, and `field` is often blank.